# Do Vimeo support Android Native playback for my app end users?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player, vimeo-android, vimeo-ios

I am developing a virtual classroom app for coaching centers

I want to use Vimeo native playback in Android and iOS app of the students

Does Vimeo support Android /iOS Native playback for my app end users?

Because I cant understand the terms in their repo

> Native playback
>
> ```
> The basic requirements for native playback are:
>
> User must be logged in.
>
> User must be the owner of the video.
>
> User must be PRO or higher (or the app must have the "can access owner's video files" capability).
>
> Token must have the video_files
> scope.
>
> User must be the owner of the API app making the request.
> ```

please explain me

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Vimeo supports native playback for Android and IOS. An example of this can be referenced to [ct7ct7ct7's Android-VimeoPlayer](https://github.com/ct7ct7ct7/Android-VimeoPlayer) on GitHub.

For extra features, it looks like the app owner must have a PRO account in order to make the video look custom to your application.

You can read more about it [here](https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224969968-Embedding-videos-overview) under embedding videos in vimeo.